# Upgraded Angular 11 to 14 facing Failed to compile error on ng serve command

Tags: angular

i updated angular CLI and another lib to a similar version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioTAQ.png)

tried

1. removed node_module
2. removed pacakge-lock.json
3. npm install

still getting failed to compile error and other lots of error like this

```
Error: src/app/modules/infogeon-kpi/kpi-criteria/kpi-criteria.component.html:218:84 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known propertyof 'input'.

218                                                 *ngIf="selectTypeList.length == 0" [(ngModel)]="filterColumnValue"
                                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/infogeon-kpi/kpi-criteria/kpi-criteria.component.ts:29:16
    29   templateUrl: './kpi-criteria.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component KpiCriteriaComponent.


Error: src/app/modules/infogeon-kpi/kpi-criteria/kpi-criteria.component.html:282:99 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known propertyof 'input'.

282                                     <input type="text" class="form-control input-txt" name="uint" [(ngModel)]="unit"
                                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/modules/infogeon-kpi/kpi-criteria/kpi-criteria.component.ts:29:16
    29   templateUrl: './kpi-criteria.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component KpiCriteriaComponent.
```

[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "infogeon-angular-ad-hoc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.6",
    "@igniteui/material-icons-extended": "^2.11.0",
    "@material/icon-button": "^10.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-option-highlight": "0.0.5",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.1",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
    "angular-timezone": "^1.0.4",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^5.0.4",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1233.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^1.0.0",
    "cuppa-ng2-slidemenu": "^2.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fine-uploader": "^5.16.2",
    "firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "googleapis": "^72.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "igniteui-angular": "^14.2.2",
    "image-to-blob": "^0.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "minireset.css": "0.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-gapi": "0.0.94",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.3",
    "ng2-completer": "git+https://github.com/dilankamr/ng2-completer.git",
    "ng2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-avatar": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-masonry": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-slickjs": "^1.5.2",
    "ngx-spinner": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-splitinput": "^0.7.3",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.16.105",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1402.6",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.0",
    "@igniteui/angular-schematics": "^14.1.1005",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.14.4",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "open": "^7.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

and

app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } 
from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { HeaderComponent } from 
'./components/shared/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from 
'./components/shared/footer/footer.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from 
'./components/shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { Ng2CompleterModule } from "ng2-completer";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-   browser/animations';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';
// Recently added for Slide bar
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
// import { NgOptionHighlightModule } from '@ng-select/ng-option-highlight';
// import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
// import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
// import { NgOtpInputModule } from 'ng-otp-input';
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  HeaderComponent,
  FooterComponent,
  NavbarComponent,
],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 CommonModule,
 AppRoutingModule,
 FormsModule,
 HttpClientModule,
 Ng2SmartTableModule,
 Ng2CompleterModule,
 Ng2SearchPipeModule,
 NgxPaginationModule,
 NgxSpinnerModule,
 NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
   // set defaults here
   radius: 100,
   outerStrokeWidth: 16,
   innerStrokeWidth: 8,
   // outerStrokeColor: "#78C000",
   // innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
   animationDuration: 800,
 }),
 // NgSelectModule,
 // NgOptionHighlightModule,
 // CKEditorModule,

 // NgOtpInputModule,

 HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
   cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
   headerName: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
  }),
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  NgbModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  AngularMultiSelectModule
 ],
exports: [
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  AngularMultiSelectModule
],
providers: [CookieService, DatePipe],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}

declare module "@angular/core" {
 interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
 ngModule: Type<T>;
 providers?: Provider[];
 }
}
```

please help me out this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share details about your module? And also share package.json

Comment: Please add the module file as well.